# Как в определённом классе добавить методы?

Tags: ооп, java

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с архитектурой приложения. 
Я пишу маленькую программку, которая работает с базой данных. Я хочу сделать мини-версию того, как в настоящих проектах работает с JDBC, по меньшей мере с точки зрения архитектуры, и возможности легко вносить изменения в уже работающее приложение. 
У меня есть общий обобщённый интерфейс с самыми базовыми функциями, такими как: добавить, удалить, обновить и т.д., через который будет происходить работа с таблицами баз данных. Далее имеется абстрактный класс, наследующий от интерфейса, в котором эти самые базовые функции реализованы, ну и добавлена пара абстрактных методов, которые реализуют уже конечные классы.
Сами конечные классы - это менеджеры, которые соответствуют каждой таблице в базе данных.

```
IManagerDao->AbstractManager->ClientManager  - >MySQL
```

Теперь сам вопрос: если мне нужно в определённом классе добавить методы (к примеру, в классе AccountManager, который ходит в бд и вытаскивает данные из тaблицы Accounts), то как мне это сделать? Ведь вызывать эти классы рекомендуется через их общий интерфейс:

```
IManagerDao client = new ClientManager();
```

Но в таком случае я не буду иметь возможности пользоваться методами класса AccountManager.   Как поступают в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Вы можете сделать промежуточный интерфейс IClientManager с нужными методами и таскать его по программе.

Но для действительно маленькой программы обычно обобщать `AbstractManager` смысла нет. Особенно когда вы используете JDBC напрямую и запросы надо собирать руками.

PS. Слово `Manager` в имени класса - не очень хорошо. Обычно слой доступа к данным называют `Dao`. Ну и там `AbstractDao > ClientDao > ClientMysqlDao`, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам в таком случае нужен интерфейс, если за ним идет следующий уровень абстракции в виде абстрактного класса? Либо ваш интерфейс должен содержать сигнатуры всех необходимых методов (и тогда отпадает необходимость в абстрактном классе), либо откажитесь от интерфейса в пользу абстрактного класса. Если абстрактный класс содержит какую-то общую для всех своих наследников логику, то вам следует отказаться от интерфейса. Если же таковой логики нет, то уберите абстрактный класс и дополните интерфейс необходимыми методами. Абстракции, это, конечно, хорошо, но плодить их сверх меры не стоит

Comment: Абстрактный класс реализует методы интерфейса, такие как добавить, удалить, выбрать и тд. Он нужен для того что бы не переписывать их реализацию из класса в класс. Конечные классы(менеджеры в моём случае) наследуют этот абстрактный класс, и реализуют лишь несколько добавленных методов. Например для каждой таблицы SelectAll будет отличаться так же как и ResultSet.

Comment: Замечательно. Зачем в таком случае интерфейс?

Comment: Я понял, спасибо.

Comment: Так в чем проблема-то? Вам нужна некая абстрактная сущность, которая будет позволять вам выполнять ряд действий, скрывая конкретные реализации, не так ли? Так почему ваш абстрактный класс не может быть такой сущностью? Вполне может.

Насколько можно судить из ваших слов, абстрактный класс определяет ряд методов, которые должны быть реализованы во всех классах-наследниках (если они должны быть реализованы **не во всех** наследниках, то это уже нарушение принципа подстановки Лисков, и это ошибка архитектуры тащемта), следовательно, он вполне подходит на роль этой абстрактной сущности

Comment: Да, все методы реализованны всеми классами наследниками. Проблема возникла, когда у одного из классов наследников мне пришлось добавить новые методы, которые должны быть видны из другой части программы. Но создавать этот объект напрямую я не хочу. А создавая его через интерфейс, эти методы не видны.

Comment: @Remind, @DreamChild есть такой довольно распространенный в около-enterprise проектах паттерн для DAO слоя, который опирается на базовый интерфейс в качестве контракта и на абстрактный класс в качестве базовой реализации:
![uml](http://i.imgur.com/AGBGXEk.png)

Answer (score 2):

Интерфейсы определяют контракт для их имплементаций. Если ваша имплементация нарушает контракт, то это ошибка дизайна (за редкими исключениями). Т.е. в идеале в ваших имплементациях не должно быть публичных методов, которые не объявлены в интерфейсе.

По вашей иерархии классов: кажется, что она усложнена. По идее, вам достаточно определить интерфейсы DAO (например, ClientDao), а их имплементации для разных БД могут просто лежать в разных пакетах. Абстрактные классы для каждой сущности кажутся лишними.

Comment: Так абстрактный класс он один, от него и наследуют все конченые классы, работающее с БД. Но в целом нужно, либо добавлять ещё методы в интерфейс, что бы они подходили для всех таблиц, либо менять архитектуру, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Remind, в чем суть этого абстрактного класса? Почему он должен быть в этой иерархии? Не кажется вам, что в вашем дизайне все DAO должны имплементировать один интерфейс, а это неправильно, т.к. над разными сущностями возможны разные действия.

Comment: Ну, чтобы избежать дублирования однотипных функций из класса в класс. Например, функция delete будет реализована во всех классах, так к чему просто повторять её реализацию? Наверное, вы правы, и стоит сделать несколько интерфейсов. Спасибо.